# Converting MP3 to Video with Single/Multiple images as video with PHPVideoToolkit

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Just started using PHPVideoToolkit and I'm looking to take an MP3 and convert it to a video. I want to have a single image as the video with the audio playing.

On the Google Code page https://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/ it says it can `assemble a video stream from a set of separate video images` so I know it's possible but I cannot figure out how from the GitHub documentation.

The documentation found in the `documentation` directory of the repository appear to be empty.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

## Turning Images into Video

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

This command will transform all the images from the current directory (named `image1.jpg, image2.jpg`) to a video file named `video.mpg`.

## Playing music in the video

```
ffmpeg -i song.wav -i video.avi video_finale.mpg
```

This command will add a `song.wav` in `video.avi` and give a final `video_final.mpg`

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking to do it through PHPVideoToolkit not directly through ffmpeg.

Comment: @Wasim doesnt PHPVideoToolkit run on ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes it does but running the ffmpeg command directly doesn't allow me to use the API and I would need to create my own progress monitor, error handling etc.